# separate log file for different classes in same package

Tags: logging, log4j

I am using the log4j and wanted to create different log files for different classes in the same package,I can perform this by using two xml files but I want to perform it by using a single xml file.

Please tell me the way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Make all classes which should log to the same file use the same logger, e.g. place the following Logger instantiation in each class:

```
Logger firstFileLogger= Logger.getLogger("firstFile");
```

In your `log4j.xml` declare a corresponding logger

```
<logger name="firstFile>
  <level value="debug"/>
  <appender-ref ref="firstFileAppender" />
</logger>
```

and let it log to a corresponding file appender:

```
<appender name="firstFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
  <param name="file" value="firstFile.log"/>
  <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100KB"/>
  <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p %t %c - %m%n"/> 
  </layout> 
</appender>
```

Repeat this for each log file you want to write.